# how to let eclipse cdt show runtime error (e.g. segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I develop and run C++ program in Eclipse CDT on Linux.

The problem is that Eclipse CDT does't show any runtime error message (e.g. segmentation fault) in console, while I can get such error message when running program directly with command line.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: yes, with debug mode I can get the error message. I just wonder if the "normal run" can give out the messages as well.

Comment: I remember getting a "segmentation fault" error in galileo/ganymede. I am not getting the same after I started using eclipse regularly recently. I now use the latest, greatest release, helios. The console is simply blank.

Answer (score 8):

You could try to modify the run configuration like this

- tab 'Main' > Application = `/bin/sh`
- tab 'Arguments' > 'Program arguments' = `-c "Debug/name_of_executable arg0 arg1 ... 2> /dev/stdout"`

(replace "arg0 arg1 ..." with your program arguments, if any)
The eclipse console will output both stdout, stderr and the segmentation fault message (prefixed with "/bin/sh: line 1 ...")

**note:**  I used this solution on an older release of eclipse for which the symptoms are the same.

Comment: It is a solution for the original problem but note that you cannot debug your program with such run configurations (since eclipse will think the program you want to debug is sh, breakpoints in your code won't trigger)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the debugger instead of just running the executable!

I had the same problem when trying to import an existing c++ solution into CDT. I found it a bit odd that Eclipse didn't report anything in case of an segmentation fault. If you use the debugger, it will notify you of the segmentation faults and point you to the correct place in the code.